# How can I find the hyperlinks referring to the cell in Excel ? Reverse of Hyperlink

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink, cell, traceability

Hi I want to find a way to trace back the hyperlinks that are referring to the cells.
For Eg:
There are 5 random cells in A column referring to D2 cell via hyperlink. So when I go to D2, how can I know what are the cells that are referring to D2.

Your answers are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the hyperlinks **Inserted** or created using the *HYPERLINK()* worksheet function ??

Comment: Hyper links are created per cell by right clicking the cell and clicking on "Insert Link", later linked to a cell in the same workbook (different sheet)

Answer (score 0):

### Detect Specific Hyperlinks

- In column `A` of one worksheet, tries to find the cells that are linked to cell `D2` on another worksheet and writes the addresses of the found cells to the Immediate window.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub detectHyperlinks()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1"
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dCellAddress As String = "D2"
    
    ' Define Source Column Range.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(srcName)
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Range(srcFirst).Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range(cFirst).Resize(LastRow - .Range(cFirst).Row + 1)
    End With
   
   ' Define Destination Address String.
    Dim dAddr As String
    dAddr = dstName & "!" & dCellAddress
    
    Dim cel As Range    ' Current Cell in Source Range
    Dim sAddr As String ' Source Address String
    
    ' Iterate through cells in Source Column Range.
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        ' Evaluate if current cell does not contain an error or blank value.
        If Not IsError(cel) And Not IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then
            ' Evaluate if current cell contains a hyperlink.
            If cel.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
                ' Write current cells Sub Address to Source Address String
                ' and remove the "'" and "$" characters.
                sAddr = Replace(cel.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress, "'", "")
                sAddr = Replace(sAddr, "$", "")
                ' Allowing different case (vbTextCompare), evaluate
                ' if Source and Destination Address Strings are equal.
                If StrComp(sAddr, dAddr, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    ' Do what you need to do with the found cell.
                    ' For example print its address to the Immdediate window.
                    Debug.Print cel.Address
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```